# USB HDD disk not recognized in BIOS Boot order

Tags: ubuntu, bios, usb-flash-drive, uefi, bootable-media

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 along with Windows 8.1. Obviously I used a USB drive to install Ubuntu. I made all changes to UEFI so I could boot from USB. I could see the USB in the Boot Menu and was able to change the Boot Priority Order so my USB: HDD was first option.

After installing Ubuntu, it seems the UEFI now only has 8 entries and USB HDD has been removed, so I cannot boot from USB drive anymore, which is annoying.

I have Phoenix SecureCore Tiano version P09RAP. My laptop is a Samsung NP300E5C.

In the Boot Menu I only see now

1. ubuntu
2. ubuntu
3. Windows Boot Manager
4. SATA HDD: ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB
5. SATA CD: SlimtypeDVD A DS8A8SH
6. USB CD:
7. USB FDD:
8. NETWORK

Fast BIOS Mode is Disabled Secure Boot is Disabled OS Mode Selection is set to UEFI and CSM OS Internal LAN is Disabled

(although I have tested lots of different BIOS configurations)

I have another Samsung laptop (same model) without Ubuntu installed and the original entries in the Boot Meny Priority Order were:

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. Windows Boot Manager
3. SATA HDD: ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB
4. SATA CD: SlimtypeDVD A DS8A8SH
5. USB CD:
6. USB FDD:
7. USB HDD:
8. NETWORK

Looks like, when I installed Ubuntu and GRUB (2.02 beta2-15), one of the Windows Boot Manager entries and the USB HDD: were replaced by 2 ubuntu entries... and now I cannot boot from my USB HDD. And looks like the 2 ubuntu entries are no different, since I put both as first boot option and the behavior was the same. So my question is... how do I remove one of the ubuntu entries and get USB HDD back?

Comment: What happens when you boot either of the Ubuntu entires with the USB HD plugged in?

Comment: I get GRUB in both cases, then Ubuntu boots

Comment: And Ubuntu is on the USB HDD? So isn't it working? Is it different if you use a different USB HDD that doesn't have Ubuntu on it? Windows 8 & UEFI are "funny" compared to the way computers normally boot for the last 25yrs... And it does look like Ubuntu replaced the Windows bootloader too, it usually does that and puts an entry in grub to boot windows.

Comment: No, Ubuntu is on the hard disk. And Windows 8.1 is also on the hard disk. I dont have any problem booting one or the other. If I put ubuntu as first option, it will launch GRUB and then I can pick Windows or Ubunutu. If I put Windows Boot Manager, then Windows 8.1 boots directly. Issue is that I can not boot from my USB HDD anymore since it does not appear in the list of Boot Device Priority (and before installing Ubuntu, it did appear because I installed Ubuntu from a USB HDD!!). And the USB works fine once I boot any OS (I can access the USB HDD from Ubuntu or Windows).

Comment: Ah, I thought "used a USB drive to install Ubuntu" meant that you installed Ubuntu to the USB HD, and had to do changes to boot from the USB HD. I'd guess that Ubuntu did something to the BIOS/UEFI to undo (at least some of) the "*changes to UEFI so I could boot from USB*" you did. Try reviewing what you did the first time, may need to do them again.

Comment: I did not do anything... just installed Ubuntu... and it has removed USB HDD from the devices list and, instead, now I have an entry called "ubuntu" (in fact 2). The only thing that comes to my mind is to restore the system completely, but, when I install Ubuntu again, I will loose the USB HDD entry (if I ever get it back restoring the laptop to factory OS)